# std::vector conversion to cl_float

Tags: c++, opencl, stdvector

I have been struggling with getting a two dimensional vector into an openCL float array.

Defining a test array and a dynamic vector as such:

```
double ABCD[2][2];                                      //Works
vector< vector<float> > Jacobian(0, vector<float>(0));  //Doesn't work
cl_float *input_float;                                  //openCL Input Array
```

I am doing a lot of work with the Jacobian in a C++ program and need to eventually pass it to the openCL program.

```
input_double = *ABCD;       //works fine in the openCL program
input_float = Jacobian;     /*error C2440 no suitable conversion 
                            from std::vector to cl_float exists*/
```

No amount of playing with pointers is making this work.  Any ideas on how I can get a dynamic vector into the cl_float structure?  There is a dearth of documentation IMHO.

Eventually, I am placing it in its own buffer and working on it inside the GPU.

```
inMapPtr = clEnqueueMapBuffer(
                    commandQueue, 
                    inplaceBuffer, 
                    CL_FALSE, 
                    CL_MAP_WRITE, 
                    0, 
                    SIZE_F, 
                    0, 
                    NULL, 
                    &inMapEvt, 
                    &status);
memcpy(inMapPtr, input_float, SIZE_F);
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers are not arrays. Arrays are not pointers. `double ABCD[2][2];` is not a length 2 array of pointers to `double` pointing to 2 arrays of 2 `double`s; it is a single memory block of 4 `double`s with syntactic sugar that convert the pair of indices into the right index.

A `vector` of `vector`s is a completely different data structure, and can not be interpreted as a multidimensional array. `vector` supports single dimensional arrays only.

```
input_float = Jacobian;     /*error C2440 no suitable conversion 
                            from std::vector to cl_float exists*/
```

You would need something like

```
input_float = Jacobian[0][0];
```

`vector` instances don't decay into pointers automatically like built in arrays.

Comment: You surely meant to write `&Jacobian[0]`. ... and I doubt that this would work, either, because it would be a pointer to a `std::vector<float>`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: No, I didn't. The example this is being compared with does `input_double = *ABCD;` which dereferences the first element in the array.

Comment: input_float = Jacobian[0][0]; gives me an error 'value of type float cannot be assigned to type cl_float.

Comment: That worked, I just had to add it to a loop. I will post the working code.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked:

```
int i = 0;
for (int x = 0; x <= 2; x++)  // loop 3 times for three lines
{
     for (int y = 0; y <= 2; y++)  // loop for the three elements on the   line
     {
        input_float[i] = Jacobian[x][y]; // copy to input_float
        i++; 
     }
}
```